# asp.net webform existing codebased how to prevent XSS Attack

Tags: asp.net, security, xss, owasp

We have existing ASP.Net Application 3.5. We have done Security Audit and we found that we can have XSS attack with our application.

As we have existing application and more than 100 modules - can we have easy way where with some configuration (minimal effort rather than going to every page and encode output).

We also have few pages where we need to allow even HTML Editor as well.

Please suggest me the easy and quick way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

> As we have existing application and more than 100 modules - can we have easy way where with some configuration (minimal effort rather than going to every page and encode output).

There are hacks, like the built-in ASP.NET “Request Validation”, or the “Security Runtime Engine” in MS Anti-XSS, which attempt to filter out what it thinks might be an attack on the way into your application.

These are generally a very poor solution in the long term, because they can't address all possible attacks and they'll break some input that isn't an attack. But this might be a useful temporary workaround measure until you can fix the app properly to escape everywhere it puts strings into a containing context, and set suitable development standards and controls to stop more context-naïve templating getting into the codebase.

> We also have few pages where we need to allow even HTML Editor as well.

You will need an HTML sanitiser library to filter out all but acceptable whitelisted tags/attributes. Here is [one](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer).